# How to programmatically log Bluetooth activities (Paired, Unpaired, Connected, Disconnected) on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

The targeted app will be running as a background service, tracking Bluetooth activities (Paired, Unpaired, Connected, Disconnected) of the device. Is this feasible (i.e. does Android security allows an app seeing the BT activities)?

Much appreciated~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible for an app to be notified of every Bluetooth events occuring on an Android device.

What your app can do though is listing the Bluetooth devices currently bonded with the Android device hosting the app. Here is how:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

You can also scan for all the bluetooth devices around, and use the scan records they advertize to read infos such as their RSSI (i.e. their signal strength) and manufacturer data.